# The difference between (sender as) and (new) in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#, these days I'm studying this tutorial from msdn.microsoft.com (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492172.aspx),

a part of this tutorial there is a statement to make a new object as think but I'm not sure for a numeric up down control, and the statement is:

```
NumericUpDown answerBox = sender as NumericUpDown;
```

and it's on this page 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492138.aspx)

the question is, what is the difference between these two statements?, and what both mean.

```
NumericUpDown answerBox = sender as NumericUpDown;
```

and

```
NumericUpDown answerBox = new NumericUpDown();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They have nothing to do with each-other, except that they each declare a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *very* different.

1. `NumericUpDown answerBox = sender as NumericUpdown;`

   In this case you are casting the object being passed into your function to a object of type `NumericUpDown`, so you can safely use the properties and methods defined in that class.
2. `NumericUpDown answerBox = new NumericUpDown();`

   In this case you are creating a *completely new object* of type `NumericUpDown` that has no relation to the object being passed in. Any methods you call or properties you access on this new instance will have no effect on the `sender`<sup>*</sup>.
   <sub>(*Disclaimer: unless the class is doing some strange things with static members)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you put the code back into context you can see that:

```
private void answer_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Select the whole answer in the NumericUpDown control.
    NumericUpDown answerBox = sender as NumericUpDown;
}
```

`object sender` has already been defined as an `object` called `sender` that has been passed into the function.

What the line `sender as NumericUpDown;` is doing, is parsing the `object` into a `NumericUpDown` for use within the function.

So there is no similarity between [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This one creates a new instance of `NumericUpDown`:

```
 new NumericUpDown();
```

`As` is used to perform conversions between compatible types.

```
sender as NumericUpDown;
```

See MSDN:

[as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When a NumericUpDown is entered (the event the tutorial has you subscribe to), Windows Forms passes the specific NumericUpDown box that was entered as the `sender`.  `sender` is an Object, which means anything could be passed in, as many objects have events like this.  You need to tell the compiler that this `sender` is a NumericUpDown, which is what the first does.

The second creates an entirely new NumericUpDown which isn't on any forms, so is basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, is actually taking the object "sender" and casting it as the "NumericUpDown" type. It's closer to the following casting code: "(NumericUpDown)sender", with the key difference being that the "as" operator returns null if the type of "sender" is not able to be cast to the NumericUpDown type, whereas (NumericUpDown)sender will throw an InvalidCastException.

The second statement, "NumericUpDown answerBox = new NumericUpDown()", is creating a new instance of the NumericUpDown type using its parameterless constructor.